# Mypy Invalid index type "str" for "Union[str, Dict[str, str]]"; expected type "Union[int, slice]"

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Why am I getting the error? I have added the type properly, right?

```
Invalid index type "str" for "Union[str, Dict[str, str]]"; expected type "Union[int, slice]"
```

Code

```
from typing import List, Dict, Union

d = {"1": 1, "2": 2}

listsOfDicts: List[Dict[str, Union[str, Dict[str, str]]]] = [
    {"a": "1", "b": {"c": "1"}},
    {"a": "2", "b": {"c": "2"}},
]

[d[i["b"]["c"]] for i in listsOfDicts]
```

Comment: [d[i["b"]["c"]] for i in listsOfDicts if isinstance(i["b"], dict)]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mypy expects dictionaries to have the same type. Using `Union` models a subtype relation, but since `Dict` type is invariant, the key-value pair must match *exactly* as defined in the type annotation—which is the type `Union[str, Dict[str, str]]`, so the subtypes in the `Union` wouldn't get matched (neither `str`, `Dict[str, str]` are valid types).

To define multiple types for different keys, you should use `TypedDict`.

Usage as seen here: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/more_types.html#typeddict.

```
from typing import List, Dict, Union, TypedDict

d = {"1": 1, "2": 2}

dictType = TypedDict('dictType', {'a': str, 'b': Dict[str, str]})

listsOfDicts: List[dictType] = [
    {"a": "1", "b": {"c": "1"}},
    {"a": "2", "b": {"c": "2"}},
]

[d[i["b"]["c"]] for i in listsOfDicts]
```